How to Fetch Data from Supabase Backend Every Re-render in React Native?
I'm trying to get my library app to fetch data from backend every time a change is made to the database. For example, if the user deletes a library from the database, I want the dropdown with the selection of libraries to update and remove the deleted library from the list.
The problem is, once the library is deleted from the database, the dropdown does not re-render. The user still sees the deleted library in the list of selections.
Here's the link to a video of the problem:
Video
Here's the code for the library screen:
// Expo 
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';
import { Stack } from 'expo-router';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';


// App Backend
import { styles } from '../../assets/stylers';
import Colors from '@/constants/Colors'; 
import { useLibraries } from '../backend/fetch_libraries';
import LibraryMenu from '../../components/LibraryMenu'; 


// React
import { View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';


export default function Library() { 

    const libs = useLibraries()
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);
    const [menuVisible, setMenuVisible] = useState(false);
    const [addLibMenuVisible, setAddLibMenuVisible] = useState(false);
    const [deleteLibMenuVisible, setDeleteLibMenuVisible] = useState(false);
    const [editLibMenuVisible, setEditLibMenuVisible] = useState(false);
    const [libraryKey, setLibraryKey] = useState(50)



    return (
        <View style={menuVisible || addLibMenuVisible || deleteLibMenuVisible == true ? {opacity: 50} : {opacity: 100}}>
            <Stack.Screen 
            options={
                {
                    headerStyle: styles.HeaderStyle, 
                    headerTitleStyle: styles.HeaderTextStyle, 
                    headerRight:(() => <View style={styles.libraryHeaderView}>
                                            <Dropdown
                                                style={styles.libraryDropDownScroll}
                                                itemContainerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownItem}
                                                containerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownContainer}
                                                data={libs}
                                                labelField="label"
                                                valueField="value"
                                                placeholder='All'
                                                onChange={item => {setFocus(false)}}
                                                onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
                                                onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
                                                renderRightIcon={() => focus == false ? <Ionicons name="arrow-down" size={26} color={Colors.black} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/> : <Ionicons name="arrow-up" size={20} color={Colors.black} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/>}
                                                />
                                            <TouchableOpacity onPress={
                                                () => menuVisible || addLibMenuVisible || deleteLibMenuVisible || editLibMenuVisible == true ? (function () {
                                                    setMenuVisible(false)
                                                    setAddLibMenuVisible(false)
                                                    setDeleteLibMenuVisible(false)
                                                    setEditLibMenuVisible(false)
                                                })() : setMenuVisible(true)}>

                                                <Ionicons name="menu" size={35} color={Colors.black} style={styles.librarySettingsIcon}/>
                                            </TouchableOpacity>
                                        </View>
                                    )
                    
                    }
                }/>
            
            <LibraryMenu 
                menuVisible={menuVisible} 
                visibleMenuFunc={setMenuVisible} 
                addLibMenuVisible={addLibMenuVisible} 
                visibleAddLibMenuFunc={setAddLibMenuVisible}
                deleteLibMenuVisible={deleteLibMenuVisible}
                visibleDeleteLibMenuFunc={setDeleteLibMenuVisible}
                editLibMenuVisible={editLibMenuVisible}
                visibleEditLibMenuFunc={setEditLibMenuVisible}
                libraryKey={libraryKey}
                setLibraryKey={setLibraryKey}/>
            

        </View>
        );
    };

Here's the code for the library menu:
// React
import { View, Text, Alert, TouchableOpacity, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Dropdown } from 'react-native-element-dropdown';


// Backend
import { styles } from '../assets/stylers';
import Colors from '@/constants/Colors';
import SupabaseFunction from '../app/backend/supabase_actions';
import { useLibraries } from '@/app/backend/fetch_libraries';



// Expo
import Ionicons from '@expo/vector-icons/Ionicons';



const LibraryMenu = (props) => { 
    const libs = useLibraries()
    const [folderName, setFolderName] = useState([]);
    const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false)
    const [lib, setLib] = useState([])
    const [newFolderName, setNewFolderName] = useState([])
    const [error, setError] = useState(false)

    if (props.menuVisible == true) { 
        return (
            <View style={styles.menuView}>
                <View style={styles.libraryMenuHeadingAndCloseIcon}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuHeading}>Actions</Text>
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryCloseButtonTouchable} onPress={() => props.visibleMenuFunc(false)}>
                        <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                                    props.visibleMenuFunc(false)
                                                    props.visibleAddLibMenuFunc(true)
                                                }} style={styles.libraryMenuActionButtons}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuButton}>Add New Libraries</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                                    props.visibleMenuFunc(false)
                                                    props.visibleDeleteLibMenuFunc(true)
                                                }} style={styles.libraryMenuActionButtons}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuButton}>Delete Libraries</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>

                <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {
                                                    props.visibleMenuFunc(false)
                                                    props.visibleEditLibMenuFunc(true)    
                                                }} style={styles.libraryMenuActionButtons}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuButton}>Rename Libraries</Text>
                </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
        )
    }

    if (props.addLibMenuVisible == true) {
        return(
            <View style={styles.menuView}>
                <View style={styles.libraryMenuHeadingAndCloseIcon}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuHeading}>Add Library</Text>
                    <View style={styles.libraryButtonsView}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryBackTouchable} onPress={() => {
                                                                                                    props.visibleAddLibMenuFunc(false)
                                                                                                    props.visibleMenuFunc(true)
                                                                                                }}>
                            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryCloseTouchable} onPress={() => props.visibleAddLibMenuFunc(false)}>
                            <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.librarySubView}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryAddNamePrompt}>Name</Text>
                    <TextInput style={styles.libraryAddNameTextInput} onChangeText={(e) => setFolderName(e)} ref={input => {libraryNameRef = input}}/>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.librarySubView}>                                                                                  
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.createLibraryButton} onPress={() => {
                        if (folderName != "") {
                            SupabaseFunction("add", folderName, setFolderName, libraryNameRef)
                            props.setLibraryKey(props.libraryKey+5)
                        } else {
                            Alert.alert("Please enter a library name!")
                        }
                        }}>
                        <Text style={styles.libraryButtonText}>CREATE</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View> 
            </View>
            )
        }

    if (props.deleteLibMenuVisible == true) {


        return (
            <View style={styles.menuView}>
                <View style={styles.libraryMenuHeadingAndCloseIcon}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuHeading}>Delete Library</Text>
                    <View style={styles.libraryButtonsView}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryBackTouchable} onPress={() => {
                                                                                            props.visibleDeleteLibMenuFunc(false)
                                                                                            props.visibleMenuFunc(true)
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }>
                            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryCloseTouchable} onPress={() => props.visibleDeleteLibMenuFunc(false)}>
                            <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.librarySubView}>
                    <Text style={styles.deleteDropDownPrompt}>Library</Text>
                    <Dropdown
                        style={styles.deleteDropDownScroll}
                        itemContainerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownItem}
                        containerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownContainer}
                        data={libs}
                        placeholder='Choose a library...'
                        labelField="label"
                        valueField="value"
                        excludeItems={[{label: "All", value: "-1"}]}
                        onChange={item => {
                                            setFocus(false)
                                            setLib(item.label)
                                        }}
                        onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
                        onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
                        renderRightIcon={() => focus == false ? <Ionicons name="arrow-down" size={26} color={Colors.main} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/> 
                                                                : <Ionicons name="arrow-up" size={26} color={Colors.main} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/>}
                    />
                </View>

                <View style={styles.librarySubView}>                                                                                  
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryButton} onPress={() => {
                                                                                    SupabaseFunction("delete", lib, {}, {}, {})
                                                                                    props.setLibraryKey(props.libraryKey+5)
                                                                                    setLib("")
                                                                                        }}>
                        <Text style={styles.libraryButtonText}>DELETE</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View> 
            </View>
        )        
    }  

    if (props.editLibMenuVisible == true) {

        return (
            <View style={styles.menuView}>
                <View style={styles.libraryMenuHeadingAndCloseIcon}>
                    <Text style={styles.libraryMenuHeading}>Rename Library</Text>
                    <View style={styles.libraryButtonsView}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryBackTouchable} onPress={() => {
                                                                                            props.visibleEditLibMenuFunc(false)
                                                                                            props.visibleMenuFunc(true)
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }>
                            <Ionicons name="arrow-back" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.libraryCloseTouchable} onPress={() => props.visibleEditLibMenuFunc(false)}>
                            <Ionicons name="close" size={30} color={Colors.main} style={styles.libraryCloseIcon}/>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </View>
                
                <View style={styles.renameLibrarySubView}>
                    <View style={styles.renameSubView}>
                        <Text style={styles.renameDropDownPrompt}>Library</Text>
                        <Dropdown
                            style={styles.renameDropDownScroll}
                            itemContainerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownItem}
                            containerStyle={styles.libraryDropDownContainer}
                            data={libs}
                            placeholder='Choose a library...'
                            labelField="label"
                            valueField="value"
                            excludeItems={[{label: "All", value: "-1"}]}
                            onChange={item => {
                                                setFocus(false)
                                                setLib(item.label)
                                            }}
                            onFocus={() => setFocus(true)}
                            onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
                            renderRightIcon={() => focus == false ? <Ionicons name="arrow-down" size={26} color={Colors.main} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/> 
                                                                    : <Ionicons name="arrow-up" size={26} color={Colors.main} style={styles.closeIconStyle}/>}
                        />
                    </View>
                    
                    <View style={styles.renameSubView}>
                        <Text style={styles.renameDropDownPrompt}>New Name</Text>
                        <TextInput style={styles.libraryRenameTextInput} onChangeText={(e) => setNewFolderName(e)} ref={input => {libraryNameRef = input}}/>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.renameButtonView}>
                        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.renameLibraryButton} onPress={() => {
                            if (newFolderName == "") {
                                Alert.alert("Please enter a name!")
                            } else {
                                SupabaseFunction("rename", lib, {}, libraryNameRef, newFolderName, libs, error, setError)
                                props.setLibraryKey(props.libraryKey+5)
                            }
                        }}>
                            <Text style={styles.libraryButtonText}>RENAME</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>

                </View>

            </View>
        )
    }
}



export default LibraryMenu;

Here's the code for the JS file that fetches the libraries from the database:
// Backend
import { getItemFor } from './async_store';
import { supabase } from './supabase';
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";


// React
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';


export const useLibraries = () => {
    const [libs, setLibs] = useState([]);

        useEffect(() => {

            const fetch_libraries = async () => {
                const email = await getItemFor("email");
                
                const { data, error } = await supabase
                    .storage
                    .from('pdfs')
                    .list(`${email}/All`);
                
        
                if (data != null) {
                    const libraries = [{label: "All", value: '-1'}];
                    for (let x = 0; x < data.length; x ++) {
                        if (data[x].name.includes('.lib') == true) {
                            const lib_name = data[x].name.replace('.lib', "")
                            libraries.push({label: lib_name, value: x.toString()})
                        }
                    };

                    setLibs(libraries);
                } else {}

                if (error) {
                    console.log(error)
                }
            }

            fetch_libraries()
        }, [])

        return(libs)
};

